# Running Monaca project on Windows

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, monaca

I want to create a Cordova based monaca project on Windows. I have installed all the dependencies as following

> npm install -g cordova
>
> npm install -g webpack-cli

After that added monaca

> npm install -g monaca
>
> monaca create l360_desgn

then i have chosen vue.js with the navigation term. After that it sows this message

> Cound not find/set the custom API endpoint Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Muktar Ali.cordova\monaca_config.json'
>
> Some Windows terminals may not work correctly with the interactive template creation.
> If that's the case, please execute `monaca create --help` for an alternative solution.'

which shows this and i am not sure what to do with this

```
 >PS F:\l360_design\l360_design> monaca create --help

  >Usage: monaca create path

  >Description:

  >Creates a new application at a provided path.

  >The command downloads a list of available templates
 and then displays a list for the user to choose from.

  >The specified project will be created in a directory
 given by the user.

  >Options:

  >--url                        URL of a zip file containing a Monaca template.
  >--template-list              Prints a list of all the available Monaca templates.
  >--template                   Name of the chosen template for the project creation.

  >Examples:

  >$ monaca create myproject
  >$ monaca create --template-list
  >$ monaca create myproject --template blank
  >$ monaca create myproject --url 
  >http://github.com/me/myproject/archive/master.zip
```

Then I have used

> monaca preview

After that it shows this

> Project preview failed: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Muktar Ali.cordova\node_modules\webpack'

Please help me with this.